# While Loop Character Sequence

Tags: c++

Hi i am trying to create a program that reads in characters until the user enters the correct two character sequence (cs) to open the door. The input should be only c followed by s and also both characters. I am not sure where i am going wrong! Please help. Right now it allows access even when i enter a single word !

```
int main()
{
   char A;
   int done = 0;

   cout << "You have before you a closed door !" << endl;
   cin >> A;

   while (!done)
   {
      if (A='cs')
        break;

      else
        cin >> A;
   }

   cout << "Congratulations ! The door has opened !" << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `A='cs'` is your problem. Look up the comparison operator.

Answer (score 4):

`'cs'` is a multicharacter constant

And `A='cs'` is assignment not comparison, which also is not intended and incorrect

You should use `std::string A;`

and do comparison like following

```
if( A == "cs" ) { }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int main()
{
char A,B='cs';

cout << "You have before you a closed door !" << endl;
cin >> A;

while (1)
{
  if (A==B)
    break;

  else
    cin >> A;
}

cout << "Congratulations ! The door has opened !" << endl;

return 0;
}
```

You have done mistake in the comparison of the multicharacter constant.